# Opamp GBW is not matching with measurement

Tags: oscilloscope, photodiode, gain-bandwidth-product, transimpedance-amplifier

I have circuit below on breadboard with LF351N op-amp in transimpedance mode with feedback resistor of 10 kohm and 10 pF capacitor attached in parallel.

[image]

In datasheet of LF351N ([Datasheet](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/lf351.pdf)) it is suggested that this opamp has max 4 MHz gain bandwidth product however in my configuration I'm getting 150 kHz 3 dB bandwidth with 10 k gain (a white LED is driven by a function generator and frequency varied from 100 Hz up till 3 dB point) which expectedly should be having 150 * 10e+3 * 1 * 10e+4 = 1.5 GHz (sounds ridiculous).

[image]

In the meantime I should also underline that I'm getting an interesting behaviour during this measurement. High frequency response of this circuit is fading out on oscilloscope (weak Voltage lines) screen while low frequency response is pretty solid.

Why might this be happening?

Could someone navigate me on where I'm doing wrong or if my understanding is wrong?

Comment: As drawn, you have +5 V on both power rails of your op amp. I'm sure this isn't what you have on your breadboard, but your drawing is wrong. Also, what does it mean to have "10 kHz gain"? Gain is supposed to be unitless. And the 4 MHz figure in the datasheet is the typical value, not the maximum.

Comment: This is literally what I have (excluding transmitting LED side). Yes gain is unitless but whatever your feedback resistor value that is your gain (in my configuration at least). You are right. It' stated as typical and max column is empty on the datasheet. Any opinion on getting faded signal on oscilloscope during high frequencies?

Comment: You have a transimpedance of 10kohms which is not the same thing as a gain of 10,000. (Note the difference in units).

Comment: @LifeIsBeatiful I think this is not exactly what you have, because it wouldn't work if it was. You have the positive of a +5 V power supply providing +5 V to pin 7, and the negative of a -5 V supply providing +5 V to pin 4. Remember, two negatives make a positive.

Comment: @user1850479 I'm deleting my answer, you were quicker than me.

Comment: "the negative of a -5 V supply providing +5 V to pin 4" how is -5V supply providing +5V?

Comment: @user1850479 my input is photodiode current and opamp outputs voltage. that voltage is equal to (Photodiode current * feedback resistor). How does not the value of feedback resistor equal to gain here?

Comment: Gain does not have units of ohms.

Comment: @LifeIsBeatiful The negative terminal of a -5 V supply is 5 V *higher* than the positive terminal; that's what it means for the supply to be negative. This is in contrast to a +5 V supply, where the negative terminal is 5 V *lower* than the positive terminal.

Comment: @user1850479 Gain of a transimpedance amplifier *does* have units of Ω, that's what it means to be a transimpedance amp.

Comment: You can call transimpedance a type of gain if you like, but it's definitely not *the* gain with which you can calculate a gain bandwidth product. That gain needs to be unitless, not a resistance.

Answer (score 2):

GBW product doesn't directly apply to this circuit.

An op-amp's gain-bandwidth product refers to the product of the gain and bandwidth that you can expect when you build a voltage amplifier circuit -- it's roughly accurate when you build a voltage amplifier with positive gain, less so for low negative gains.

When you build a stabilized photodiode amplifier like this one, the stability of the amplifier is mostly determined by the feedback capacitor (C1 in your schematic), which needs* to be roughly the same capacitance as the photodiode's capacitance.  Then the actual bandwidth *should be* determined by the product of the feedback capacitance and resistance (i.e., \$R_2 C_1\$ for this circuit).

In your case, \$\frac 1 {2 \pi R_2 C_1} \simeq 1.6 \mathrm{MHz}\$.  This doesn't match what you're measuring, so I suspect that there's more going on in your circuit than meets the eye**.

---

* If I recall correctly -- I'm sure there's a nice rule of thumb, but I build these circuits seldom enough that I either arrive at the value by experiment or by analysis.

** Or I'm missing something important, and someone needs to step in and correct me.

Comment: In addition to RC limitation, bandwidth of Closed loop configuration is also impacted by the feedback resistor in relation with Open loop (or unity) gain bandwidth product. This is what I have understood from below tutorial
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UooUGC7tNRg

Comment: any opinion on faded signal on Oscilloscope at higher frequencies?